# Forward iterator/random acces iterator and `operator*` over temporary iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, random-access, temporary-objects

Is this:

```
auto& ref1 = *it++;
ref1 = expression; // (1)
```

one of the required semantics of a forward iterator? And what about a random access iterator?

```
auto& ref1 = it[3];
ref1 = expression; // (2)
```

According to `cppreference`, a forward iterator is required to:

```
// Return reference, which equals to (const) value_type &
*it++ === value_type&
```

and for a random access iterator:

```
it[n] === *(it + n)
```

which is the same situation, which means that in both situations you are dereferencing a temporary (the iterator). In my case, my iterator stores by copy an index which allows to access a container which doesn't provide direct access to the stored elements, only through the index.

That works fine:

```
*it++ = value;
```

since the temporary copy of `it` has sentence scope.

But in this case:

```
type& val = *it++;
val = 3;
```

we get undefined behaviour, since the copy is already destroyed in the second line.

In my situation, I have a `QModelIndex` wrapper to get data/save from/to a `QAbstractItemModel`. The model only gives you copies of the `QVariant`s stored on the model.

My wrapper class (the `value_type` with the `operator=` overloaded) saves an instance of a `QModelIndex` (to manipulate the model), and the iterator an instance of that wrapper. So, if the iterator is destroyed, the wrapper and the index too.

I think I can solve both problems as far as lines `(1)` and `(2)` don't need to be supported.

*NOTE:* My implementation is more or less like that (simplified):

```
// The value type
struct index
{
    QModelIndex qidx;

    index& operator=(QVariant const& val)
    {
        if (qidx.isValid())
            qidx.model()->setData(qidx, val);

        return *this;
    }
};

// Private class actually. The "movements" cannot be done
// over the value type because it will cause, in functions
// returning references to the value type, to increase the chaos.
// So, I make the index points to different model items using
// this class.
struct index_manipulator
{
    QModelIndex& qidx;

    void move(int rows, int cols)
    {
        if (qidx.isValid())
            qidx = qidx.model()->index(qidx.row() + rows,
                                       qidx.column() + cols);
    }
};

struct index_safe_ref
{
    mutable index idx;
    operator index&() const { return idx; }
};

struct my_row_it
{
    index idx;
    index_manipulator manip = {idx.qidx};

    my_row_it(QAbstractItemModel* m, int col)
        : idx(m ? m->index(0, col) : QModelIndex())
    {}

    index& operator*() const { return idx; }

    my_row_it operator++(int) const
    {
        auto copy = it;
        manip.move(1, 0);
        return copy;
    }

    index_safe_ref my_row_it::operator[](difference_type n) const
    {
       auto it = it + n; // Operator+ is over there.
       return { it.idx };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A stashing iterator (that is, an iterator that returns a reference to something within itself) is never a valid forward iterator.

Iterators in general must be [`CopyConstructible`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/utility.arg.requirements#tab:copyconstructible) ([[iterator.iterators]/2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterators#iterator.iterators-2.1), which requires, among other things, that a copy of the iterator be equivalent to the original. It follows that a forward iterator and its copy must necessarily compare equal, and [[forward.iterators]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterators#forward.iterators-6) requires that that for two equal dereferenceable iterators `a` and `b`, `*a` and `*b` must be bound to the same object, which cannot be satisfied for stashing iterators.

If you need to ignore a requirement, I suggest ignoring the one that says `reference` must be an actual reference type, turning your stashing iterator into a proxy iterator. There's established practice for that in the standard library (`vector<bool>::iterator`) and any breakage is likely to be a loud compile-time error, rather than silent runtime mischief.

Comment: I'm my case, two copies of the same iterator, refers to the same element (the inner `QAbstractItemModel` item), because two copies of a same iterator has two copies of a `QModelIndex` which refer to the same element in the `model`. As I said in the other comment, in my case, `*it == *(my_row_it(it))`, but, `&*it != &*(my_row_it(it))`. So, what is the meaning of "be equivalent to the original"? Two copies of a same iterator don't return the same object, but return a proxy to a same object.

Comment: Even though, in the `cppreference` documentation at least, none of the requiered features speaks about the address of the returned object, and there's no way of knowing if two objects are really the same unless you compare their `addressof`.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered by a general statement about iterators:

> Destruction of an iterator may invalidate pointers and references previously obtained from that iterator.
>
> §24.2.1/9 [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

But, as T.C. points out in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43270580/1116364) your iterator cannot be a valid forward iterator (or anything more strict then) if you return a reference to an object contained within the iterator object.

I see two solutions: Return that `index` object by value, or return a reference to a heap allocated `index` object.

---

As a note, an *input iterator* needs to support this:

```
value_type temp = *iterator++; // or *iterator; ++iterator;
// use temp
```

So in your case this must work (but should as far as I can see):

```
index temp = *iterator++;
temp = expression.
```

This is not the same as line `(1)` because above code involves a conversion to the value_type (and not a reference to it).

Comment: My Iterator support this. Two copies of the same iterator refer to the same item. Which my iterator doesn't fullfill is &*it == &*(my_row_it(it)).